# GtkBox implicit margin between children

Tags: gtk3, margins

Is it possible to remove all margins between two widgets inside a GtkBox?

**Tried:** Set everything to zero

**Result:** Still 2px effective margin

**GTK+ Version**: 3.18.9

**Widget properties:**

[image: Widget properties 1]

[image: Widget properties 2]

**Drawing code:**

```
auto w_out=static_cast<double>( gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(widget) );
auto h_out=static_cast<double>( gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget) );

cairo_set_source_rgba(cr,self->m_background.red,self->m_background.green
    ,self->m_background.blue,self->m_background.alpha);
cairo_rectangle(cr,0,0,w_out,h_out);
cairo_fill(cr);

auto img=self->r_img;
if(img!=nullptr)
    {
    //...
    }
```

The actual size is 22 x 22 as expected.

**Rendered result**:

[image: Result]

It appears that this is not a theming issue, since all themes behaves the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had a non-zero spacing for the GtkBox.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried on the same Gtk version:

```
$ rpm -q gtk3-devel
gtk3-devel-3.18.9-1.fc23.x86_64
```

and it did work without any borders as can be seen:

[image: Screenshot]

The images are centered due to horizontal alignment set as center. Resizing the window to the smallest size:

[image: Screenshot]

The image used was a crop from the original (22x22 px):

[image: Screenshot]

**Conclusion**

Seems that you are creating a custom widget, maybe there's something you're missing (more details needed). From regular widgets (GtkImages packed on a GtkBox, tested with glade) it seems to work fine.